# Monad Transformers document: eval1 doesn't typecheck

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm reading through the [Monad Transformer](http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.pdf) document.
And I have come across this code sample:

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad.Identity

type Eval1 a = Identity a

runEval1 :: Eval1 a -> a
runEval1 ev = runIdentity ev

type Name = String
data Exp = Lit Integer
         | Var Name
         | Plus Exp Exp
         | Abs Name Exp
         | App Exp Exp
         deriving (Show)

data Value = IntVal Integer
           | FunVal Env Name Exp

type Env = Map.Map Name Value
```

And they write evaluation function for that:

```
eval0 :: Env -> Exp -> Value
eval0 env (Var i) = fromJust $ Map.lookup i env
```

And another evaluation function with monadic style:

```
eval1 :: Env -> Exp -> Eval1 Value
eval1 env (Var n) = Map.lookup n env
```

(I'm just showing part of the `eval1` function where I have problem)

The `eval0` function typechecks but `eval1` doesn't typecheck. So is this error in that document or am I missing something ?

Also they go on explaining about `eval1` like this:

> Var case does not need a fromJust call anymore: The reason is that
>   Map.lookup is defined to work within any monad by simply calling the
>   monad’s fail function – this fits nicely with our monadic formulation
>   here. (The fail function of the Maybe monad returns Nothing, whereas
>   the fail function in the Identity monad throws an exception, which
>   will lead to different error messages.)

But is `Map.lookup` defined to work with any monad ? (It's type signature indicates that it retuns a `Maybe` value.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually see this code in the document for `eval1`, which should typecheck fine (I re-indented it):

```
eval1 env (Var n) =
    maybe (fail ("undefined variable: " ++ n)) return $
        Map.lookup n env
```

It seems that `Map.lookup` did earlier have the more general signature: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html

Since the document dates from 2006 and still has the text you quote above stating that `Map.lookup` has the more general signature, but a footnote at the beginning saying "Ported to newer GHC in 2012", I think that the code has been updated but the text hasn't.

**Edit:**

I tracked down the history of the change in `Map.lookup`, dating from 2008: [Code change](https://github.com/haskell/containers/commit/cf99591f4bfda31b3c713b5ccf17e83b7d819963), [Trac ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2309), [Libraries list discussion](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2008-May/009698.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find the code you mentioned above in that document. Can you tell what it's page number? (The code for eval1 in the pdf document I pointed out is in page 4 like this: `eval1 env (Var n)
= Map.lookup n env`

Comment: I see the code I quoted about 2/3rds of the way down on page 4. Do you perhaps need to get a fresh copy or something? The footnote suggests that the document was updated in 2012.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm having an old copy of the document.